# Perform the following block multiplications

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

[image]

i understand this process. but i do not understand that how may i calculate this. kindly tell me.

Comment: Just proceed “formally” as if the blocks were numbers and then do the matrix products in the final blocks.

Answer (score 0):

in (a) preform the matrix multiplication with the letters. then you will have a new 2x2 matrix with letters O,I and the B's. For example, element 11 will be O(B11)+I(B21). Now you will make a substitution for the matrices into each of the four elements and repeat multiplication and then addition. The solution element 11 for (a) is matrix[3 1; 3 2]. Good luck...